# Conditionally define Elastic Beanstalk environment variable using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to create an Elastic Beanstalk using CloudFormation template. I want to define an environment variable `ENV_VAR_1` and set it's value to value of template parameter `var1`. But don't want `ENV_VAR_1` to exist at all if  `var1` is an empty string. I.e. I don't want `ENV_VAR_1` with no value.

First I tried the [`Conditions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html), but I get `"Encountered unsupported property Condition"` during creation of `ElasticBeanstalkEnvironment` resource.

```
Parameters:
  var1:
    Type: String

Conditions:
  isVar1Empty: !Equals [ !Ref var1, "" ]

Resources:
  ElasticBeanstalkEnvironment:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment'
    Properties:
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment'
          Condition: isVar1Empty
          OptionName: ENV_VAR_1
          Value: !Ref var1
```

Then I tried `AWS::NoValue`

```
Parameters:
  var1:
    Type: String

Resources:
  ElasticBeanstalkEnvironment:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment'
    Properties:
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment'
          OptionName: ENV_VAR_1
          Value: !If [[!Equals [ !Ref var1, "" ]], !Ref 'AWS::NoValue', !Ref var1]
```

and many permutation combinations of this. With the same result: When `var1` is empty, Elastic Beanstalk gets created with `ENV_VAR_1` set to `""`

Comment: !Equals is not allowed within a Fn::If block ... so what you claim above will not work.  Yeah, I know your issue is how to avoid setting the variable (even to null or empty string)  if the condition is not met, but just pointing this out so other people don't get confused by the obvious error in the code have shared

Answer (score 5):

Conditions are going to be applied at the Resource level...currently, you cannot apply a condition to a specific property.

What you could do to satisfy these exact requirements (and this is a bit ugly), is create two conditions, one negating the other.  Then with these two conditions, have them conditionally create the specific resource.

```
Parameters:
  var1:
    Type: String

Conditions:
  isVar1Empty: !Equals [ !Ref var1, "" ]
  isVar1NonEmpty: !Not [ !Equals [ !Ref var1, "" ] ]

Resources:
  ElasticBeanstalkEnvironmentWithVar1:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment'
    Condition: isVar1NonEmpty
    Properties:
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment'
          OptionName: ENV_VAR_1
          Value: !Ref var1
  ElasticBeanstalkEnvironmentWithoutVar1:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment'
    Condition: isVar1Empty
    Properties:
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment'
```

Like I said...a bit ugly.  Note that this will only really work well if you have one or two variables like this.  As soon as you add a second or third 'optional' parameter, this quickly starts spiraling out of control.

A better option might be to generate your CloudFormation template using a templating library like [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/).

Comment: Yeah, this is slightly better than my backup plan to have 2 separate templates. Thanks!

Comment: Not an option for resources that occupy many lines of code.   OK suggestion, I guess, for shorter lines of code or if one is really desperate

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround to handle conditions at option level:

```
Conditions:    
    CreateProdResources: !Equals [!Ref Env, "prod"]

EBEnvironment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties: 
      OptionSettings: 
       - Namespace : "aws:elasticbeanstalk:command"
         OptionName: Timeout
         Value : 1200
       - Namespace : !If [CreateProdResources, "aws:elbv2:listener:443", "aws:elasticbeanstalk:command"]
         OptionName: !If [CreateProdResources, Protocol, Timeout]
         Value : !If [CreateProdResources, HTTPS, 1200]
       - Namespace : !If [CreateProdResources, "aws:elbv2:listener:443", "aws:elasticbeanstalk:command"]
         OptionName: !If [CreateProdResources, SSLPolicy, Timeout]
         Value : !If [CreateProdResources, "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08", 1200]
       - Namespace : !If [CreateProdResources, "aws:elbv2:listener:443", "aws:elasticbeanstalk:command"]
         OptionName: !If [CreateProdResources, SSLCertificateArns, Timeout]
         Value : !If [CreateProdResources, !Ref ACMCertificate, 1200]
```

Repeated options are considered only once in Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Good suggestion, but setting timeout has it's own considerations too.  I guess the logic is to find a safe parameter, even if it's to re-set the default, and use it as a fallback.  That can save many lines of code, especially for verbose resources like elasticbeanstalk

Comment: Timeout is an example that I used in my scenario. You can use any parameter that you are already using in your EB environment. And yes, we can even re-set the default just to achieve this.